# Maintain page settings when reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on building an 'account settings' form.

Each LI tag is a different section.. eg: Update username, Update email, Update password.
like so..

```
<li>
    <header>Title</header>
    <div>Content</div>
</li>
```

I use Jquery to toggle the content when the title is clicked (The content is automatically closed when the page loads).

When I submit POST data (effectively refreshing the page), I would like to retain the divs that haven been opened so than i can display text.. eg "Your passwords do not match", "Your password has been changed successfully!".

I would like to do something along these lines: 
Send post data which can be picked up by CSS (or code that can modify css), which would apply a class to the content div.

Preferably, i'd not like to send post data to Jquery because of the response time. But if that is the only option, i'd love to hear it!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try using ajax to check the fields without having to "refresh" the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this (just draft, not poetry :-) )

when your 'handler.php' processed information, callBack information

```
if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $openornot= 'open';
}else{
    $openornot='notopen';
}
```

on your tag class :

```
<div class="<?php echo $openornot; ?>">content</div>
```

and in you script.js, something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".notopen").hide();
});
```

just draft lines...

or ajax as [kiee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072075/kiee) said : )

Comment: This is Brilliant! I've found that the Jquery at the end isn't needed if you set css selectors for the outputted names. Eg. 'Form ul li div.content.on {}', 'Form ul li div.content.off {display:none}' ...Thanks so much :-)